# Why can't I create multiple labels using a for loop in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm taking Python courses and I'm on Tkinter now. I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe board using a 'x' and 'o' gifs. But my code won't display all cells, it will only show the last row, last column image. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Tic-Tac-Toe Board')

        r = 0
        c = 0

        for i in range(9):
            rand = randint(0, 1)
            img = PhotoImage(file = 'image/cross.gif' if rand == 1 else 'image/circle.gif')
            Label(window, image = img).grid(row = r + 1, column = c + 1)
            print('Displaying', 'circle' if rand == 0 else 'cross', 'at', r + 1, c + 1)
            c += 1
            if c % 3 == 0:
                r += 1
                c = 0

        window.mainloop()

TicTacToe()
```

[image: This is what is displayed when I run it]

Can somebody explain why this code isn't working? Any can you tell me the fix?

Comment: Because you aren't keeping references to the images - the last `img` is getting discarded each time around the loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe brilliant...thank you. I kept the `img`s in a `list` and it works now,